How to write karma jasmine tescases to cover code for Ag grid col defs for valueformatter , tooltipvaluegetter
{
    headerName: this.translateService.instant('_updated_date_'),
    field: 'lastUpdateDate',
    headerTooltip: this.translateService.instant('_updated_date_'),
    valueFormatter: (params: any) => params?.value ? this.utilService.dateFormatter(params.value, TmLinkConstants.DATE_FORMAT) : '',
    minWidth: 120,
    tooltipValueGetter: (params: any) => params?.value ? this.utilService.dateFormatter(params.value, TmLinkConstants.DATE_FORMAT) : ''
  }

Tried to write coverage this but doesnt seem to take any.

First convert them to their own individual functions
const valueFormatter = (params: any) => params?.value ? this.utilService.dateFormatter(params.value, TmLinkConstants.DATE_FORMAT) : '';

const tooltipValueGetter = (params: any) => params?.value ? this.utilService.dateFormatter(params.value, TmLinkConstants.DATE_FORMAT) : '';
...

...
{
    headerName: this.translateService.instant('_updated_date_'),
    field: 'lastUpdateDate',
    headerTooltip: this.translateService.instant('_updated_date_'),
    valueFormatter: valueFormatter,
    minWidth: 120,
    tooltipValueGetter: tooltipValueGetter,
  }
  ...

Then coverage becomes simple
desc('valueFormatter', () => {
    it('should return value', () => {
        spyOn(utilService, 'dateFormatter').and.returnValue('TEST');
        expect(valueFormatter({value: 'test'})).toEqual('TEST');
    })
});

desc('tooltipValueGetter', () => {
    it('should return value', () => {
        spyOn(utilService, 'dateFormatter').and.returnValue('TEST');
        expect(tooltipValueGetter({value: 'test'})).toEqual('TEST');
    })
});

